# scraping all links of clips in twitch directory

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, twitch

How do i collect links of clips from twitch web page ?

I want to get links for all video clips from twitch directory like
[this](https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Apex%20Legends/clips?fbclid=IwAR2xYPFh3Um2YS4EsDkjAdA0b-CMvjQTLVLeNW5D77-aPh3IqwW9c4e7lIM&range=24hr)

I tried requests with BeautifulSoup, failed, then Requests with lxml, failed too.

I tried selenium webdriver to find clip links by xpath and click on each one

> driver.find_element_by_xpath('__').click()

but failed too despite xpath expressions are correct.

How do i collect links of clips from twitch web page ? please help.

Comment: I would start [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-clips) and then come back when you get stuck and/or have some code to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the video clip urls using the below XPath :

```
xpath = //a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']
```

But the above will locate only the first 20 urls and after that you need to do scroll down so that it will load dynamically from there. For getting the first 20 urls you can try the below code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Apex%20Legends/clips?fbclid=IwAR2xYPFh3Um2YS4EsDkjAdA0b-CMvjQTLVLeNW5D77-aPh3IqwW9c4e7lIM&range=24hr")
sleep(3)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")
for link in links:
    print link.get_attribute('href')
```

If you count manually by inspecting, there are 1020 clips are there in that page. So below code will scroll down until all the clips are loaded and will prints all the links :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Apex%20Legends/clips?fbclid=IwAR2xYPFh3Um2YS4EsDkjAdA0b-CMvjQTLVLeNW5D77-aPh3IqwW9c4e7lIM&range=24hr")

sleep(3)
i = 1
while i <= 1020:
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', links[len(links)-1])
    print "=> i :", i
    i+=20
    sleep(1)

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")
for link in links:
    print link.get_attribute('href')

print("=> Done...")
```

I hope it helps

Comment: work fine but return one link, It doesn't accept loop on link, is it because driver.find_element_by_xpath return only the first occurrence instead of list?

Comment: What is that means? Can you share which link it is returning? For me it is returning 20 links

Comment: It is `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")` not `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` --- There is a difference between `element` and `elements` so use `elements`

Comment: yes, my mistake, I forgot the s, how can i get the rest of links, by scrolling down using selenium? any solution?

Comment: Yes, you need to do scroll down and get it

Comment: can you help me please, I don't know how to scroll down correctly using selenium, I do scrolling to the bottom of the page or scroll the page with infinite loading?

Comment: perfect, it works, thanks, i will up vote, can we chat privately? my email is koubaakhaled@gmail.com